# Move to multisite to other local

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I want to move my multisite to another local. Using MAMP Pro.

PHP version 5.3.2

Copied my site files to new directory. And disk location `mysite/sites/multisitename/`

Installed exist database and configure. It's OK. But when I go to site link, get this error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Checked my files and everything is OK.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you access files directly? With full URL to an image, for example?

Comment: Yes, all link is normal.

Comment: may be this is related to .htaccess or virtual hosts? This is a web server error, not database..